# SKLearn decisionTreeClassifier does not handle sparse or categorical data

Tags: scikit-learn, decision-trees

Is there a way in fitting a decisionTreeClassifier in SKLearn to sparse tuples? The data that I have is based on about 100 features, but only a few of them are ever used to make the decision. Effectively, each row of data is a sparse tuple.

My input data is 30k entries like:

```
(yes if f1=v1 and f3=v2) 
(no  if f1=v3 and f5=v4)
...
```

and so on.

There are tens of thousands of entries and the conclusions are not necessarily consistent. My goal is to find an automated method to reduce this down to tens of nodes that approximate the same behaviour. I need access to the resulting structure - which is why I have considered using SKLearn rather than, say DataRobot.

My understanding of the use of SKLearn decisionTreeClassifier is that I have to convert this to a array of tuples of 100 values, and have the features just be given an index number. But, that means I have to provide a value for every one of the 100 features on every row. And that does not well represent the data that I have.

---

This is like having data to be classified looking like

```
(yes,v1,__,v2,__,__)
(no ,v3,__,__,__,v4)
```

Hence, the interest is in, for example, being able to list the value of the data as None to indicate that there is no constraint on that field.

The data as given has only equalities. But, the expected output will have inequalities, since that appears to be what SKLearn provides. I would really prefer a decision tree with equalities and inequalities.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a don't care value for a feature. The example you show tests two equalities. Decision trees don't work like that. Each node tests X > t, where X is the feature's value, and t is some threshold. If you don't want a decision tree to use a feature, simply remove it fromthe dataset.

Comment: @pseudoabdul I will expand on the terms and concepts in the main body of the question.

Comment: Is this a machine learning problem (there is uncertainty) or can this be solved by a bunch of known rules? If you know the logic, then write the rules in a programming language or logic language (prolog).

Comment: @Craig Imagine the scenario of a numeric data table to which you need to fit a decision tree, perhaps using Data Robot. But, most of the entries are Nulls. Each row has only a few non Null entries. My description above is just another way of describing such a sparse table. It is a perfectly reasonable thing to train a decision tree on this table. This is a machine learning task. But, apparently, SKLearn decisionTreeClassifier is sadly incapable of doing this. My goal is to produce a simplified approximation using tens of nodes instead of tens of thousands. That is also a machine learning task.

Comment: I do not quite understand the problem. But if you are looking for a tree tool that supports categoricals and missings - H2o, rpart, lightgbm, catboost. There are also other encodings you can do for the categoricals. Target, riser, and more. [Patsy](https://patsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/categorical-coding.html) implements many encoding schemes.  Once encoded, you can use any tree package. I do not use 1-hot in my work since there are better options. I also searched for sparse trees and high dimensional trees and found some papers that might help you.

Comment: @Craig do you mean rpart in the R language? I have more or less decided this is not going to work in sklearn without a lot of fuss - and have started to rewrite the code in R using rpart. (I am not deeply familiar with rpart, so that will be part of the tmie spent). Or can I get that for Python? Although, I think I have committed to R now anyway.

Comment: rpart for R. You can call R from Python, checkout rpy2, but rpart is an R package. H2o, lightgbm, catboost all can be called from R or Python. xgboost, if you encoding the categorical yourself can also be called by R and Python.

Comment: @Craig I have been slogging away at this since I last modified this post. Thanks for your suggestions. You could probably put something together that I would accept as an answer. But, I have another question - I have written the code in RPart and it works in a clunky sense of the word, but I did not find how RPart supports missing data. What were you meaning there?

Comment: Glad you are getting closer to solving the problem. rPart uses [surrogate splits](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rpart/versions/4.1-15/topics/rpart.control) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/171574/meaning-of-surrogate-split/) for missing, if configured. Surrogates are other split features to use for missing. Say Feature A is the best splitter. Calculate surrogates (the 2nd, 3rd, ... best splitter) to use if feature A is missing. If surrogate is missing, move to the next. If your data is very sparse may need a lot of surrogates or surrogates may not work.

Comment: @Craig Thanks for bringing this to my attention. It is useful to know. There would have to be a hundred surrogate splits as a minimum. And the real problem is the way the fitting process responds to the missing data. I suspect that it would not work. But, I am going to try to get assigned some time to develop a modification of some binary logic reduction methods I used some years since.

Answer (score 0):

My own investigation on this forum and on SKLearn bug reports and forums is that the core of the problem - that SKLearn decision tree classifier does not handle categorical or sparse data - has been complained about for some years with no important changes to the code in this respect.

Three approaches suggest themselves. Firstly, expand out the tuples to non-sparse with some default value such as 0 for all the don't-care cases with the idea that the constancy of this value will result in SKLearn being forced to use other values to make the decisions on. Secondly, to shift the circus to R - where, apparently, the equivalent routines actually do handle categorical and sparse data. Or, thirdly, write the decision tree training code myself from scratch.

It is my intention to come back later and tell you how that worked out for me.

Comment: Hi @Bruce, how did you end up solving the problem?

Comment: Hi @Dudelstein, the short version is that I ended up pretty much writing everything myself. I did use the entropy partitioning part of the R module code. But, the rest was pretty much all mine. I have not had time to get into the Quine reduction stuff, as shortly after asking this question most of the code was switched to Sagemaker and Python anyway. I filled blanks with a very large number so that if the module used it, it would be very obvious.